# Can`t submit my modal form in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

A Django beginner needs help here! I'm trying to upload image in a modal form, the problem is I can't submit my modal...when I click the submit button nothing actually happpen...been struggling this for 2 days...
I'm using Bootstrap V 1.0.4
tried some JS codes from the net but none of them worked for me... any idea what  should I do? thanks...
here`s my modal:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">

                         <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">آپلود عکس</h4>
                          </div>
                         <div class="modal-body">
                          <p>کاربر گرامی لطفا قبل از آپلود عکس به موارد زیر توجه نمایید:</p>
                             <ul>
                                 <li>حداکثر حجم قابل قبول برای فایل ارسالی 8 مگابایت می باشد</li>
                                 <li>فرمت های تصویری مجاز: jpg , Gif , PNG</li>
                                 <li>در صورت ارسال عکس های غیراخلاقی عکس و طرح شما به هیچ وجه منتشر نخواهد شد و پس از چاپ از سیستم حذف می گردد</li>
                                 <li>لطفاً در هنگام آپلود عکس صبور باشید :)</li>
                             </ul>
                         </div>
                         <div class="modal-footer">
                             <form method="post" action="/upload/" id="formfield">
                                 {% csrf_token %}
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="upload">آپلود عکس:</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="upload" name="upload"/>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="sides">چند رو بودن(1-پشت/2-جلو/3-هر دو طرف):</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sides" name="sides"/>
                                 </div>
                                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">ذخیره</button>
                            </form>
                         </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
```

sorry the if the form is in persian.
views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        print "entered upload"
        image=request.POST.get('upload', False)
        sides=request.POST.get('sides', False)
        design=Design.objects.create(image=image, sides=sides)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
```

since I can`t submit my modal it doesn`t even enter my `upload` def in views.py.
any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: if you are dealing with files in forms, you need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as a form attribute. And in the views, you would do `request.FILES.get(...)`. You are better off using a django form in this case - for security, validation for file types, etc..

Comment: Also, check the browser's console to see if you encounter any 404 or 500s .

Comment: Last time i'm facing like this problem before.. Working with bootstrap modal making form then press submit button. And nothing happen. So weird right. You know what problem is? The problem acctually cause by the same name defined on input type submit for attribute. Like yours having id and type attribute with `submit` name.. Try change id name.. Not sure this solution work on not for this case..

Comment: Thank you @karthikr you did a great help. I did what you said. thanks again :)

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali thanks man. you are right the id thing sometimes causes problems, but it was not mine in this case. thanks for trying to help any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `data-dismiss="modal"` on submit button, which is a bootstrap handler for closing the modal box. The bootstrap is catching this event and preventing default submit event as its purpose is to close the modal. Just remove the `data-dismiss="modal"` from submit button and you are good to go. Also follow the tips by `karthikr`

Comment: Thanks dude! you`ve been a lifesaver. I removed the data-dismiss="modal" and it worked! =O

Comment: @ParmisMoghadamian Glad I helped you. You can mark answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you think its a valid answer.

Comment: Yes!  This has been driving me crazy!!  Thanks!